# Database design for creating polls

Tags: database, database-design

I'm fairly new to database design. I would like to design a poll/vote system, where user can create a question and provide multiple answer choices for people to vote. And the table should be able to see for each answer, how many people have voted for. I'm not sure how to create DB tables like that. Can someone help me here?

Many thanks :)

Comment: You should Google a bit first, before asking a question. https://www.google.nl/search?q=poll+database+schema&tbm=isch

Answer (score 0):

I just did something like this, actually.
This is what I did:

survery_session:  Creates a record at time of user entry.  Everything ties back to here.
surveys_are:  Holds the name of the survey, type, and if it's active
survey_questions:  links to surveys_are.id, holds questions, order, active, and type
survey_answers:  links to surveys_are.id and survey_questions.id. Holds the possible answers for each question.  When called up, it provides a list of stuff to make radio groups with.
answers_are:  links to all the other stuff, and holds user responses.  Each form submission will have a list of one row per question

Now, there is a lot more to this.  But that's the basic idea.  If you want to see what it looks like, check out this link:  http://dpoisn.com/surveys/

I had literally developed it exactly as you describe.  It's made to be scalable.  It can handle an indeffinite number of new surveys, and each survey can hold an indefinite number of questions.  The only limitation is that I got lazy with the radio lists.  Can't have more than 6 options.

EDIT:  Sorry for my formatting here.  My browser is not showing the cool tools for formatting my post.